# Cutting a config file down to size

Tags: configuration, config, grammar

Morning!

I've got an app with a config file that's become unwieldy - many switches with no intuition as to which combinations are valid. Right now, all the switches are stored in an XML file. The config file specifies inputs for a large HPC job.

I'm thinking of writing some a formal grammar for a run - that is, the sort of combinations that are acceptable, and from the parsing of it, the switches needed will automatically be inferred. The values would still be read from the XML file, but only when needed.

Is this sort of approach reasonable? How would I go about implementing a grammar without a parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to implement a Domain Specific Language (DSL), the purpose of which is to specify validation rules for the contents of an XML-based configuration file.

Some people implement a DSL by defining a parser specific to the needs of the DSL. However, some other people shoehorn the semantics of their DSL into the syntax of an existing file format, such as XML or JSON. So if you want to avoid having to write a parser, you could express your DSL in XML syntax.